# How can I make a Thinkpad T61 with Intel-4965 AGN behave as an access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

How can I make a Thinkpad T61 with Intel-4965 AGN behave as an access point?

Connectify does not support it. The OS can be Windows 7 or Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: I'm going with Windows 7 due to the first google result for Connectify.  For Ubuntu 10.10, hostapd does support intel-4965 through iwlwifi per: http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi

Comment: Possible duplicate of this, wireless internet connection sharing: http://serverfault.com/questions/29117/windows-7-wireless-connection-sharing